# Converting latitude and longitude to float in C

Tags: c, floating-point, latitude-longitude

I'm trying to convert Lat and Lon coordinates to 4 decimal place float. I have 'working' code, but it's just a bit off like %50 of the time. Can anyone help me or have a better design to make it more exact?

```
 float sexag2decimal(char * deg){
    char *sdeg = malloc(sizeof(char)*3);
    char *smin = malloc(sizeof(char)*3);
    char *ssec = malloc(sizeof(char)*3);
    char *ssec2 = malloc(sizeof(char)*5);
    int size = strlen(deg);
    int m = 0;
    for(m = 0; m < size-1; m++){
        if(deg[m] >= 65 && deg[m] <= 122){
            return 0;
        }
    }
    float converted = 0;
    if(deg[0] == '0'){
        strcpy(&sdeg[0], &deg[1]);
        strcpy(&sdeg[1], &deg[2]);
        strcpy(&smin[0], &deg[4]);
        strcpy(&smin[1], &deg[5]);
        strcpy(&ssec[0], &deg[7]);
        strcpy(&ssec[1], &deg[8]);
        strcpy(&ssec2[0], &deg[10]);
        strcpy(&ssec2[1], &deg[11]);
        strcpy(&ssec2[2], &deg[12]);
        strcpy(&ssec2[3], &deg[13]);
    }else{
        if(deg[14] == 'W')
            return 0;
        strcpy(&sdeg[0], &deg[0]);
        strcpy(&sdeg[1], &deg[1]);
        strcpy(&smin[0], &deg[3]);
        strcpy(&smin[1], &deg[4]);
        strcpy(&ssec[0], &deg[6]);
        strcpy(&ssec[1], &deg[7]);
        strcpy(&ssec2[0], &deg[9]);
        strcpy(&ssec2[1], &deg[10]);
        strcpy(&ssec2[2], &deg[11]);
        strcpy(&ssec2[3], &deg[12]);
    }
    sdeg[2] = '\0';
    smin[2] = '\0';
    ssec[2] = '\0';
    ssec2[4] = '\0';
    converted = atoi(sdeg) + ((float)atoi(smin)/60.0) + (((float)atoi(ssec)+((float)atoi(ssec2))/10000)/3600.0);
    free(sdeg);
    free(smin);
    free(ssec);
    free(ssec2);
    return converted;
}
```

Thanks!

Input:

30-25-30.7140N, 086-53-37.8590W

29-57-33.3000N,081-20-23.0000W

My output:

30.4252,-86.8939

29.9592,-81.3397

Correct output:

30.4252,-86.8938

29.9593,-81.3397

Thanks!

Comment: Please show your test cases - what are your inputs, what are your expected outputs, what are the actual outputs?  How much is "just a bit"?  Four decimals to represent degrees is asking up to 7 digits of precision.  Float has 6, worst case.  Suspect you probably need to read [this](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Comment: It's been along time since i touched c but I suspect you want 10000.0 and not 10000 as dividing by 10000 is probably doing integer division.

Comment: Added the inputs and outputs mine and the correct ones

Comment: Instead of using `strcpy`, you can use assignment: `sdeg[0] = deg[0]` instead of `strcpy(&sdeg[0], &deg[0])`. `strcpy` is improper in this case, as the memory pointed to by `sdeg` is smaller than that pointed to by `deg`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: Given your test cases and results, what you're seeing is precision, representability, and rounding errors.  The `float` type has limited precision.  Suggest you read the links above.

Comment: I haven't understood yet why float is so popular compared to double. If your first choice is float, you will often get insufficient precision like here.

Comment: First, the great part of time this function wastes seems to be in `malloc`. You have no reason to use dynamic help at all: just allocate character arrays like `char sdeg[3];`
Second, `strcpy` is inappropriate here: just copy the character. `strcpy` requires NUL-terminated string and copies full length of source. That's not the thing you need here.

Comment: Third: if you check input for saneness, excluding character range 65...122 isn't good idea. Particularly, you reject the case it's 'W', despite later you expect 'W' as a possible input character.

Comment: In general, I suggest using `sscanf`. With it, you can write code like: `if (sscanf(deg, "%d-%d-%d.%d", &n1, &n2, &n3, &n4) == 4) { return some_formula_on_n1...n4;}`

Comment: Finally, `float` accuracy is definitely not enough for your expectations. 1/10000 of second (which in turn is 1/3600 of a degree) is 1/6,480,000,000 (of a full degree range 0...180) that is much smaller than `float` relative error (1/8,388,608). Switch to `double` in all values. Also, request to print at least 10 significant digits. 6 default ones are too small.

Comment: BTW for `malloc` - each `return` from function not from the last line causes 4 memory leaks. Again, you don't need it at all.

Comment: don't use `malloc` for those cases. Why waste too much memory and CPU cycle to allocate them when they'll perfectly be fine on stack

Answer (score 1):

OP's code suffers from attempting to write outside allocated buffers.  [@cyclaminist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49956694/converting-latitude-and-longitude-to-float-in-c#comment86936884_49956694)

```
float sexag2decimal(char * deg){
  char *sdeg = malloc(sizeof(char)*3);  // Too small for the entire string
  ...
    strcpy(&sdeg[0], &deg[0]); // UB: attempts to copy the _entire_ string to `deg`
```

Certainly OP meant to code something like

```
    // strcpy(&sdeg[0], &deg[0]);
    sdeg[0] = deg[0]; // Copy 1 char
```

---

> it's just a bit off like %50 of the time

Given OP's code survived the above UB, the observed output differs from expectation in part due to the result of accumulated roundings in the calculation:

```
converted = atoi(sdeg) + ((float)atoi(smin)/60.0) + 
    (((float)atoi(ssec)+((float)atoi(ssec2))/10000)/3600.0);
```

This incurs rounding in `(float)atoi(smin)/60.0`, `(float)atoi(ssec2))/10000)`, `(float)atoi(ssec2))/10000)/3600.0)` and each of the 3 additions.

Using higher precision math, like `double` rather than `float`, will dramatically reduce rounding effects,  *but not eliminate them*.

To improve accuracy, perform the calculation with no rounding with integer math.  The expected values of angle, in 10,000th of a second, needs about 36-bit math.

```
long seconds = ((atoi(sdeg) * 60) + atoi(smin)) * 60 + atoi(ssec);
long myriad_seconds = (seconds * 10000) + atoi(ssec2);
```

---

> ... to 4 decimal place float

This goal is somewhat a contradiction.    `float` is very commonly employs a *binary* encoding and so does not produce a *decimal*.  It does sound like OP want to print to 4 decimal places some `float`.  To do so, code suffers additional roundings.

The conversion of the exact `myriad_seconds` to a `float` incurs a rounding error.

```
// "29-57-33.3000N"
// myriad_seconds = 1078533000
// With infinite math, the quotient is 29.95925
float converted = myriad_seconds/(60.0f * 60 * 10000);
// The "best" `float` is just less than 29.95925
// converted = 29.959249777...
```

The conversion of a `float` to *4 decimal place text* incurs another rounding error.

```
printf("%.4f\n", converted);
// "29.9592"
```

If this is OP's goal, performing far fewer roundings like this code with greatly improve yet not eliminate the "once-in-a-while" off by one bit.

---

The originator of this task has cleverly chosen final values that are near `xxx.xxxx5...`.  These values are sensitive to the computational path  in being "just a bit off".

To counter this craftiness, consider instead of returning a `float`, return an integer of the number of 10,000th of a degree.  With error/rounding free `myriad_seconds` and controlled rounding to `myriad_degrees`, code will always achieve the expected answer - at a cost of more complex source code.

```
// Add signed half of 3600 to effect rounding (half way away from zero) before division.
long myriad_degrees = (myriad_seconds + (myriad_seconds < 0 ? -1 : 1) * 3600 / 2) / 3600;

printf("%s%ld.%04ld\n", myriad_degrees < 0 ? "-" : "", 
    labs(myriad_degrees) / 10000, labs(myriad_degrees) % 10000);

// Output 
29.9593
```

Answer (score 0):

(copied out of own comments)

First, the great part of time this function wastes seems to be in `malloc`. You have no reason to use dynamic heap at all: just allocate character arrays like

```
char sdeg[3];
```

Moreover, each return from function not from the last line causes 4 memory leaks (`free` is not called). Again, you don't need `malloc` at all.

Second, `strcpy` is inappropriate here: just copy the character. `strcpy` requires `NUL`-terminated string and copies full length of source. That's not the thing you need here.

Third: if you check input for saneness, excluding character range 65...122 isn't good idea. Particularly, you reject the case it's 'W', despite later you expect 'W' as a possible input character.

In general, I suggest using sscanf. With it, you can write code like:

```
if (sscanf(deg, "%d-%d-%d.%d", &n1, &n2, &n3, &n4) == 4) {
    return some_formula_on_n1...n4;
}
```

Finally, and the main issue: `float` accuracy is definitely not enough for your expectations. 1/10000 of a second (which in turn is 1/3600 of a degree) is 1/6,480,000,000 (of a full degree range 0...180) that is much smaller than `float` relative error (1/8,388,608). Switch to `double` in all values. Also, request to print at least 10 significant digits. 6 default ones are too small.

You could also consider the method described by @chux for only integer maths. Unlike binary floating, it's definitely free of rounding effects and hard-to-prove accuracy, despite more complex (and cumbersome).